# How do I run a form with Html+AngularJS inside a While of PHP?

Tags: php, jquery, html, angularjs

This AngularJS works like a charm, if i do this:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="ctrljs">
    <a href='#' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#mlmid'>cobacing</a>

                                <div class='modal fade' id='mlmid' tabindex='-1' role='dialog' aria-labelledby='myModalLabel' aria-hidden='true'>
                                  <div class='modal-dialog'>
                                    <div class='modal-content'>
                                      <div class='modal-body'>
                                        <form method='post' action='' name='myForm' ng-controller='formctrl'>
                                            Nomor ID Member C2G: <br>
                                            <input type='text' name='mlmidbaru' ng-model='mlmidbaru' required ng-pattern="/^[A-Za-z0-9]*$/"></input>
                                            <span class='errorcolor' ng-show='myForm.mlmidbaru.$error.pattern'><span class='label label-danger'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove'></span></span> <font color='red'>invalid value</font></span>
                                            <input type='submit' value='submit' ng-hide="!myForm.$valid"></input>
                                        </form>
                                      </div>
                                    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
                                  </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
                                </div><!-- /.modal -->

    <script>
        var app = angular.module('ctrljs', []);
        app.controller('formctrl', function($scope, $http){
             $scope.digits = {};
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

It has an awesome result that if I fill a quotes marks in that input tag, then AngularJS give a prevention, i really like it.

BUT AngularJS doesn't work (nothing happens), if I put that form inside a while on PHP whereas it has the same code, like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="ctrljs">
<?php
                $query2="SELECT * FROM t_un ORDER BY ai DESC";
                $qdb=mysql_query("$query2");
                while($fqdb=mysql_fetch_object($qdb)){
                    echo "<tr bgcolor='".($fqdb->webstatus=="inactive"?"#F6CED8":"#CEF6F5")."' id='white' onclick='swapBG(this)'><td>$no.</td><td>$fqdb->ai</td><td><a href='?namesearch=$fqdb->username&submit=yes'>$fqdb->username</a></td><td nowrap>$fqdb->namealias</td><td nowrap>$fqdb->hu</td><td nowrap><a href='#' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#mlmid'>$fqdb->mlmid</a></td><td>$fqdb->sponsor</td><td>$fqdb->upline</td><td nowrap>$fqdb->city</td><td>$fqdb->email</td><td>$fqdb->hp</td><td>$fqdb->bb</td><td nowrap>$fqdb->it</td><td nowrap><a href='?page=gantive&email=$fqdb->email' onclick=\"return confirm('Are you sure?')\">$fqdb->ve</a></td><td>$fqdb->sub</td></tr>";
?>
                                <div class='modal fade' id='mlmid' tabindex='-1' role='dialog' aria-labelledby='myModalLabel' aria-hidden='true'>
                                  <div class='modal-dialog'>
                                    <div class='modal-content'>
                                      <div class='modal-body'>
                                        <form method='post' action='' name='myForm' ng-controller='formctrl'>
                                            Nomor ID Member C2G: <br>
                                            <input type='text' name='mlmidbaru' ng-model='mlmidbaru' required ng-pattern="/^[A-Za-z0-9]*$/"></input>
                                            <span class='errorcolor' ng-show='myForm.mlmidbaru.$error.pattern'><span class='label label-danger'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove'></span></span> <font color='red'>invalid value</font></span>
                                            <input type='submit' value='submit' ng-hide="!myForm.$valid"></input>
                                        </form>
                                      </div>
                                    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
                                  </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
                                </div><!-- /.modal -->
<?php
                    $no=$no+1;
                }
?>
    <script>
        var app = angular.module('ctrljs', []);
        app.controller('formctrl', function($scope, $http){
             $scope.digits = {};
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Can anybody help me? Because i would like to use AngularJS to resolve my validation form. thanks.

Comment: can't repeat ID's in  a page, they are unique by definition. Also can't repeat same name on form since angular builds all the validation objects based on form name

Comment: Ok, very helpfull @charlietfl, maybe i will find another way to create a validation form beside AngularJS. thank you.

Comment: And this isn't at all how you should use angular. If you want to return x data from your php service, do it in a controller or service call, not in your view. If you want to loop through stuff you could f.e use an `ng-repeat` on an object.

Comment: ok, @Jan. I will try again with **ng-repeat**.